# Convert ZPL base 64 to PDF base 64

Tags: c#, pdf, zpl

My requirement is to print the ZPL using normal printer in pdf format.I am trying to convert the ZPL base 64 to PDF base 64. is there any way to do this? Thanks in advace.

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert base64-encoded ZPL to a base64-encoded PDF? If so, you'll have to render the ZPL. I imagine there might be a library for that.

Comment: Yes I want to convert base64-encoded ZPL to a base64-encoded PDF

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this easily or reliably. The ZPL specs are 1500 of pages long at last count, and i my self have had issues with renderers just for testing, the ones i found in a lot of cases didn't work. I am not sure of the use case for converting a ZPL to PDF, however this is seemingly the wrong approach, just build the label up with anything else, even html, then convert to PDF would be the easiest most reliable and maintainable solution. However if this is just a quick fix because your thermal printers are broken, hrm, im not sure what you can do, just look around

Comment: Also zebra printers have the ability to have loadable fonts and images and resources, any solution to render withou them will not work

Comment: I have got the solution by following the below link 
http://labelary.com/service.html#csharp . Thank you for all your responses  :)